# Displaying large tables of data with angular and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

We are trying to display large amounts of data on a webpage.
Data is cached, and is loaded via angular (to allow the actual page to load first and then fetch the data for the grid)

All working ok, however once the data has been received, the page freezes for 1 - 3 seconds, 
which we assume is due to the table being rendered.

Size of table can vary, and range from 20 columns 10 rows to 100 columns 100 rows.

All data has to be loaded, as it is to display trends etc.

Below is the table:-

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered" ng-repeat="Grid in userresults.Trend">
                <tr ng-repeat="item in Grid" ng-show="$first">
                    <th ng-repeat="somat in item | filter:{ColumnType :'!1'}">
                    {{somat.ColumnHeader}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in Grid">
                    <td ng-repeat="somat in item | filter:{ColumnType : '!1'}"    >
                    {{somat.ColumnValue}}
                    </td>          
                </tr>        
            </table>
```

Below is the angular:-

```
  $scope.GetPatientResults = function () {
              $("#ResultsLoader").show();

              var url = "/user/11111/GetUserResults/";

              $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        // if successful, bind success message to message

                        $scope.userresults = data;
                        $("#ResultsLoader").hide();
                        $('#ResultsSummary').show();

                    });
          };
```

is there a way to actually only build part of the table that is displayed on screen to avoid this 1 - 3 second rendering / some kind of lazy loading for tables for rows and columns?

Any help / advise is greatly appreciated as this is currently impacting usability on our system.

Comment: Try ngGrid; which I believe makes use of column/row rendering so that the browser doesn't render items not shown on screen.  If your problem is indeed the browser rendering, this should help.

Comment: @Reboog711 thank you, just had a look at the ng grid, is this type of functionality on by default?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "on".  It is not part of AngularJS; but a separate library, so you'll have to download it and add it to your app (via a JS Script tag) and I think pass it as an argument into your module definition.

Comment: we are currently using ng grid for other tables that require sorting etc, however, could not see "lazy loading" within the documentation. Is there anything in particular that we need to do for this?

Comment: I thought lazy loading was the act of loading data from the server as needed.  I do not know if the ngGrid has that feature.  However, I thought the ngGrid was built to only render the items shown on screen--not the ones shown off screen.  I could be wrong; which is why I didn't provide a formal answer.

Comment: Here is one source which verifies my understanding: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Grid-Events "When new rows are rendered in the grid: (scrolling fires this a lot)"  That text alludes to the fact that rows are rendered as the grid is scrolled as opposed to when the data is loaded.

Comment: thank you, i will try this tomorrow morning, did you want to submit as a formal answer, and i will accept if all is good.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative may be to try to use ngGrid instead of a table.  I believe that ngGrid will only render the items seen on screen, and not all grid items at once.  If your problem is indeed the browser rendering, this approach should help.

Comment: Hi, we have just tested this, and unfortunately, had no effect. The scroll also stutters when scrolling, im assuming that this could have something to do with the number of columns rather than rows?

Comment: Definitely possible.   Are you sure the issue is w/ rendering as opposed to say, transferring the data from the server to the client?  I work on one app where the amount of data loaded could be the equivalent of a small mp3 in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the <table> rendering type of the browsers. 
All browsers render tables when all the columns and rows complete, so your data delay the rendering. There is an option to make the appropriate changes in order to render everything in div or try the following [link](http://www.eriwen.com/css/use-the-table-layout-css-property-to-speed-up-table-rendering/) which says that speeds up the table layout.

```
<div id="tbl" style="float:left;" ng-repeat="Grid in userresults.Trend">
            <div  style="float:left;" ng-repeat="item in Grid" ng-show="$first">
                <div style="float:left;width:200px;" ng-repeat="somat in item | filter:{ColumnType :'!1'}">
                {{somat.ColumnHeader}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left;" ng-repeat="item in Grid">
                <div style="float:left;width:200px;" ng-repeat="somat in item | filter:{ColumnType : '!1'}">
                {{somat.ColumnValue}}
                </div>          
            </div>        
        </div>
```